# Hiding mouse cursor

Tags: c, windows, winapi, bgfx

I am using bgfx in c99 to experiment with game dev / game engine dev, so I need to hide my cursor using Windows.h / WinUser.h

However even if I use `ShowCursor(false)`, `SetCursor(NULL)` the cursor will still appear on screen.

None of the solutions I tried worked. Any help ?
Thanks

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with C99 and everything to do with Windows/Winapi

Comment: What version of windows are you testing on? Does `ShowCursor` return something? Did you try to call `GetLastError()`?

Comment: @Mathieu `ShowCursor()` doesn't use `GetLastError()` to report problems.

Comment: @Mathieu W11. I never checked what ShowCursor returned tho, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

According to [SetCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcursor#remarks),

> The cursor is a shared resource. A window should set the cursor shape
> only when the cursor is in its client area or when the window is
> capturing mouse input. In systems without a mouse, the window should
> restore the previous cursor before the cursor leaves the client area
> or before it relinquishes control to another window.
>
> If your application must set the cursor while it is in a window, make
> sure the class cursor for the specified window's class is set to NULL.([SetClassLong](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/using-cursors#displaying-a-cursor))
> If the class cursor is not NULL, the system restores the class cursor
> each time the mouse is moved.

> [ShowCursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showcursor#remarks) sets an internal display counter that determines
> whether the cursor should be displayed.(*Application-Oriented,Tried*) **The cursor is displayed only
> if the display count is greater than or equal to 0.** If a mouse is
> installed, the initial display count is 0. If no mouse is installed,
> the display count is –1.

Comment: I knew about the ShowCursor thing, tried using it in a loop until the display count was -1, didn't do a thing.
However I didn't know about SetClassLong, I'll try

Comment: `SetClassLong(nwh, GCLP_HCURSOR, NULL)` didn't work in my case.

Comment: @Edorion A console application?